# Refreshing Combo box data in extjs 4

Tags: extjs

Getting stuck on refreshing data of combo box in Extjs 4, 
on button click trying to reload combo data by reloading store -

```
Ext.StoreManager.lookup('test').load();
```

Store is reloading but data doesn't reflecting on combo box.

Is there any way?

```
 {
    xtype         : 'combo'
   ,fieldLabel    : 'Default Role'
   ,name          : 'org_default_role'
   ,store         : Ext.create('ASA.store.Roles')
   ,displayField  : 'role_rolename'
   ,valueField    : 'role_id'
   ,queryMode     : 'local'
   ,labelWidth    : 100
   ,width         : 241
   ,triggerAction : 'all'
}
```

Comment: It should do, how is your combobox bound to you store? can you show some more code please?

Comment: Hi can you please check my code i have edited my post with combo code

Comment: What if you change queryMode property to 'remote':
`,queryMode:'remote'`

Answer (score 1):

I would try
`your_combo.store.load();`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar of this situations. Cause of this behavior is that load store event performing after Filtering of store, and ComboBox has old data. I added load event hendler on store of My combo and then apply filter.

```
 my_combo.store.on({
            load: function(store, records, successful, eOpts) {
                store.filterBy(function(record) {
                    return record.get('id') != 1 && record.get('id') != 12 && record.get('id') != 777;
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your store seems to be of type `ASA.store.Roles` but your store.load() is trying to find a store called 'test'.

If you change your lookup/load call to this:

```
Ext.StoreManager.lookup('ASA.store.Roles').load();
```

Does it help?